# To set an order of initialization of objects at an application launch

Tags: cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

It is possible to  set an order of initialization of objects at an application launch?

For example:
I have two objects in IB: myObj1, myObj2. 
Both of them implement method -initWithCoder:
Properties of objects sets in IB.
myObject2 Initialize is depend from properties of myObj1.

Question: Is exist methods that set  order of  objects initialization? I must be sure that myObj1 will ALWAYS be initialized before myObject2 in runtime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read "[The Object Loading Process](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html)" in the Resource Programming Guide. Essentially if your design requires a specific loading order within the same nib, you're doing something wrong. You should put critical "once the contents of this nib/xib are loaded" code in -awakeFromNib.

If this doesn't answer your question well enough, it might be best to state exactly why the dependency you described exists.

Comment: Thank you for answer. The tutorial was very helpful  to me.
I decided to resolve my problem by implement -awakeFromNib method for my custom object. He will invoked after initWithCoder, end I can init myObj2 with myObj1 properties.